# rescue data from corupted HDD

Tags: raid, grubrescue, restore

I have Ubuntu server with **3 x 1.5TB SATA2 on Software RAID5 and LVM**, it runs as VPS Node.

This morning guy from datacenter sent me mail that **sda is corrupted** and it needs to be changed...
So he change it and found out that **sdc is also corrupted**, and I demanded that he returns old sda so that I could try to restore some files.

I installed grub-install on sdb but it's unconfigured, and on sdb1 there is only "lost+found" (I mount it in live rescue system and checked), and that is only partition that I can mount, as you can see in following (+ fsck):

```
     root@rescue ~ # ll /mnt/
    total 0
    root@rescue ~ # cd /mnt/
    root@rescue /mnt # mkdir sda sda1 sda2 sdb sdb1 sdb2 sdc
    root@rescue /mnt # mount /dev/sda /mnt/sda
    mount: /dev/sda already mounted or /mnt/sda busy
    root@rescue /mnt # mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/sda1
    mount: unknown filesystem type 'linux_raid_member'
    root@rescue /mnt # mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/sda2
    mount: unknown filesystem type 'linux_raid_member'
    root@rescue /mnt # mount /dev/sdb /mnt/sdb
    mount: you must specify the filesystem type
    root@rescue /mnt # mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/sdb1
    root@rescue /mnt # mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt/sdb2
    mount: you must specify the filesystem type
    root@rescue /mnt # mount /dev/sdc /mnt/sdc

    mount: you must specify the filesystem type
    root@rescue /mnt # 
    root@rescue /mnt # df -h
    Filesystem          Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    rootfs               12G  1.6M   12G   1% /
    udev                 12G     0   12G   0% /dev
    188.40.24.212:/nfs  1.4T  592G  722G  46% /root/.oldroot/nfs
    aufs                 12G  1.6M   12G   1% /
    tmpfs               2.4G  288K  2.4G   1% /run
    tmpfs               5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
    tmpfs               4.8G     0  4.8G   0% /run/shm
    /dev/sdb1           492M  2.9M  453M   1% /mnt/sdb1
    root@rescue /mnt # fsck /dev/sda
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
/dev/sda is in use.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.


root@rescue /mnt # fsck /dev/sda1
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
fsck: fsck.linux_raid_member: not found
fsck: error 2 while executing fsck.linux_raid_member for /dev/sda1
root@rescue /mnt # fsck /dev/sda2
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
fsck: fsck.linux_raid_member: not found
fsck: error 2 while executing fsck.linux_raid_member for /dev/sda2
root@rescue /mnt # fsck /dev/sdc
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
^C
e2fsck 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
fsck.ext2: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while trying to open /dev/sdc
Could this be a zero-length partition?
root@rescue /mnt # 
root@rescue /mnt # fsck /dev/sdb
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
/dev/sdb is in use.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.


root@rescue /mnt # fsck /dev/sdb1
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
/dev/sdb1 is mounted.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.


root@rescue /mnt # fsck /dev/sdb2
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb2

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a correct ext2
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
```

Also here is some extra info:

```
root@rescue /mnt # mount /dev/sdc /mnt/sdc
root@rescue /mnt # mount /dev/sda /mnt/sda
mount: /dev/sda already mounted or /mnt/sda busy
root@rescue /mnt # dmesg | tail -n 100
[ 5983.073733] ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[ 5983.093445] ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[ 5983.112706] ata4.00: cmd c8/00:02:1a:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 tag 0 dma 1024 in
[ 5983.112706]          res 51/04:02:1a:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[ 5983.152382] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133 (device error ignored)
[ 5983.152389] ata4: EH complete
[ 5983.152524] ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[ 5983.172225] ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[ 5983.191500] ata4.00: cmd c8/00:02:1a:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 tag 0 dma 1024 in
[ 5983.191500]          res 51/04:02:1a:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[ 5983.231138] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133 (device error ignored)
[ 5983.231145] ata4: EH complete
[ 5983.231280] ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[ 5983.250992] ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[ 5983.270263] ata4.00: cmd c8/00:02:1a:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 tag 0 dma 1024 in
[ 5983.270263]          res 51/04:02:1a:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[ 5983.309890] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133 (device error ignored)
[ 5983.309898] ata4: EH complete
[ 5983.310033] ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[ 5983.329745] ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[ 5983.349017] ata4.00: cmd c8/00:02:1a:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 tag 0 dma 1024 in
[ 5983.349017]          res 51/04:02:1a:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[ 5983.388611] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133 (device error ignored)
[ 5983.388618] ata4: EH complete
[ 5983.388847] ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[ 5983.408712] ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[ 5983.429984] ata4.00: cmd c8/00:02:1a:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 tag 0 dma 1024 in
[ 5983.429984]          res 51/04:02:1a:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[ 5983.474085] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133 (device error ignored)
[ 5983.474100] ata4: EH complete
[ 5983.474228] ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[ 5983.494517] ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[ 5983.514473] ata4.00: cmd c8/00:02:1a:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 tag 0 dma 1024 in
[ 5983.514473]          res 51/04:02:1a:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[ 5983.555572] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133 (device error ignored)
[ 5983.555587] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc]  
[ 5983.555590] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 5983.555593] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc]  
[ 5983.555595] Sense Key : Aborted Command [current] [descriptor]
[ 5983.555598] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
[ 5983.555600]         72 0b 00 00 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
[ 5983.555608]         00 00 00 1a 
[ 5983.555613] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc]  
[ 5983.555615] Add. Sense: No additional sense information
[ 5983.555619] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: 
[ 5983.555620] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 1a 00 00 02 00
[ 5983.555628] end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 26
[ 5983.575924] Buffer I/O error on device sdc, logical block 13
[ 5983.596058] ata4: EH complete
[ 5983.596189] ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[ 5983.616541] ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[ 5983.636612] ata4.00: cmd c8/00:04:1c:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 tag 0 dma 2048 in
[ 5983.636612]          res 51/04:04:1c:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[ 5983.677777] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133 (device error ignored)
[ 5983.677784] ata4: EH complete
[ 5983.677924] ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[ 5983.698262] ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[ 5983.718291] ata4.00: cmd c8/00:04:1c:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 tag 0 dma 2048 in
[ 5983.718291]          res 51/04:04:1c:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[ 5983.759539] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133 (device error ignored)
[ 5983.759553] ata4: EH complete
[ 5983.759675] ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[ 5983.779991] ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[ 5983.800041] ata4.00: cmd c8/00:04:1c:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 tag 0 dma 2048 in
[ 5983.800041]          res 51/04:04:1c:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[ 5983.841255] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133 (device error ignored)
[ 5983.841269] ata4: EH complete
[ 5983.841391] ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[ 5983.861707] ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[ 5983.881708] ata4.00: cmd c8/00:04:1c:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 tag 0 dma 2048 in
[ 5983.881708]          res 51/04:04:1c:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[ 5983.922818] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133 (device error ignored)
[ 5983.922831] ata4: EH complete
[ 5983.922952] ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[ 5983.943262] ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[ 5983.963273] ata4.00: cmd c8/00:04:1c:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 tag 0 dma 2048 in
[ 5983.963273]          res 51/04:04:1c:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[ 5984.004398] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133 (device error ignored)
[ 5984.004412] ata4: EH complete
[ 5984.004561] ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[ 5984.024824] ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[ 5984.044713] ata4.00: cmd c8/00:04:1c:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 tag 0 dma 2048 in
[ 5984.044713]          res 51/04:04:1c:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[ 5984.085733] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133 (device error ignored)
[ 5984.085741] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc]  
[ 5984.085743] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 5984.085744] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc]  
[ 5984.085745] Sense Key : Aborted Command [current] [descriptor]
[ 5984.085746] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
[ 5984.085747]         72 0b 00 00 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
[ 5984.085751]         00 00 00 1c 
[ 5984.085753] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc]  
[ 5984.085754] Add. Sense: No additional sense information
[ 5984.085755] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: 
[ 5984.085756] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 1c 00 00 04 00
[ 5984.085760] end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 28
[ 5984.106176] Buffer I/O error on device sdc, logical block 14
[ 5984.126323] Buffer I/O error on device sdc, logical block 15
[ 5984.146119] ata4: EH complete
[ 5984.146128] cramfs: wrong magic
root@rescue /mnt # 


root@rescue ~ # ll /dev/sd*
brw-rw---T 1 root disk 8,  0 Nov 18 17:56 /dev/sda
brw-rw---T 1 root disk 8,  1 Nov 18 17:57 /dev/sda1
brw-rw---T 1 root disk 8,  2 Nov 18 17:57 /dev/sda2
brw-rw---T 1 root disk 8, 16 Nov 18 17:56 /dev/sdb
brw-rw---T 1 root disk 8, 17 Nov 18 17:56 /dev/sdb1
brw-rw---T 1 root disk 8, 18 Nov 18 18:53 /dev/sdb2
brw-rw---T 1 root disk 8, 32 Nov 18 18:24 /dev/sdc
root@rescue ~ # ll /dev/md*
brw-rw---T 1 root disk 9, 0 Nov 18 17:57 /dev/md0
brw-rw---T 1 root disk 9, 1 Nov 18 17:57 /dev/md1

/dev/md:
total 0
root@rescue ~ # mdadm --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
        Version : 0.90
  Creation Time : Sun Oct 17 14:55:20 2010
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 528128 (515.84 MiB 540.80 MB)
  Used Dev Size : 528128 (515.84 MiB 540.80 MB)
   Raid Devices : 3
  Total Devices : 1
Preferred Minor : 0
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Mon Nov 18 19:40:49 2013
          State : clean, degraded 
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 1
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           UUID : acc3740a:bf0cfaea:776c2c25:004bd7b2 (local to host rescue)
         Events : 0.1416

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        1        0      active sync   /dev/sda1
       1       0        0        1      removed
       2       0        0        2      removed
root@rescue ~ # mdadm --detail /dev/md1
mdadm: md device /dev/md1 does not appear to be active.
```

If anyone has any sugestion that would be great ;)
Thanks,
Frane M.

Answer (score 1):

Many of us will use testdisk to rescue the data which was corrupted in HDD.

```
sudo apt-get install testdisk
```

will install it & sudo testdisk can launch it.

to know how to use test disk to recover your data , its different for different PC. So I cant be more specific but these links can help you.

- http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/Data_Recovery_Examples
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=387922